# visual basic 2010 how to find a "=" in a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
string = "I was born in = 1994"
```

How can I store all the values after the "=" in a var?

Comment: What did you try? What API did you consult? Did it work? If not, why not? If yes, what is the question relating to *that*? (-1)

Comment: i dint try any thing, i know i can do it i just dint know how

Comment: googlers will find this in the future and they'll all have to deal with pst's sourness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function:

```
  Dim [string] = "I was born in = 1994"
  Dim temp() As String = Split([string], " = ", -1, CompareMethod.Binary)
  'now value is in temp(1)
  MessageBox.Show(temp(1))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest way:

```
Dim var = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("="c) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, I Would go with using in string.

```
mystring as new string
mystring  = "I was born in =1994"
DataAfterEquals as string = mid(mystring,instr(mystring,"=")+1,mystring.length-instr(mystring,"=")+1)
```

You can of course use regex,  use a split, and then of course you could go really old fashion and iterate through  the string finding the equal sign.

The above code will find the first equal sign and then parsefrom that point in the string outwards, so I added the +1  to jump over the equal sign. This pseudo code.